# Symfony2 internal route in Twig render function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, routes, twig

My `layout.html.twig`:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:mainmenu')) }}
```

The `Page` controller retrieves all pages from the Doctrine and renders `mainmenu.html.twig` with a set of pages.

My `mainmenu.html.twig`:

```
{% if menu_pages is defined %}
    {% for page in menu_pages %}
        <li class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_internal') == '_page_show' and app.request.get('id') == page.id %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{{ path('_page_show', {id: page.id}) }}">{{ page.title|e }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But no `active` class is displayed. As far as I understand the problem is in internal routing. How to fix that?

Comment: What about `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Because it displays the current route of main page, not internal issued by the ``render(controller( .... ))`` Twig's method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better do not use `{{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:mainmenu')) }}`. It work more fast and comfortable when you use [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) instead. You can create a service which will show menu on any page where you include them. And in service you can easy get access to current `_route` for add `active` class.

But if you really need to use `{{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:mainmenu')) }}`, so you need pass to them a current request like:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:mainmenu', {'request': app.request})) }}
```

and then in action pass request to twig:

```
public function mainmenuAction($request) {

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:mainmenu.html.twig', array('request' => $request));
}
```

and in twig use this request:

```
{% if menu_pages is defined %}
    {% for page in menu_pages %}
        <li class="{% if request.get('_route') == '_page_show' and request.get('id') == page.id %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{{ path('_page_show', {id: page.id}) }}">{{ page.title|e }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @Victor, why do you think that `{{ render(controller()) }}` is slow? And what about  `{{ render_hinclude(controller()) }}` - do you have any experience with hinclude? I noticed, that it is slower than `render(controller())`, but it's still recomended by Symfony. Last but not least, how you want to use service instead? Do you mean about controller as service?

Comment: @Victor, you probably meant ``return $this->render`` instead just ``$this->render``? It should be a responce.

Comment: `render_hinclude` I don't use, but has experience with `render(controller())` and it work bit slower before I reorganized this to service. I create a `twig simple function` that return any service by name. And I can get access in twig to any service directly by name.

Comment: Why? :) If I need to pass in many templates of defferent actions the service, I can or pass it to each action or get them callable from twig template.

Comment: @Victor - The request will automatically be injected into magic variable `$_request` if you  add it as method parameter in the controller. there's no need to pass `app.request` from the template! Further ... controllers as services aren't generally faster ... and you can still render a controller that is a service using this syntax: `{{ render(controller('controller_service:mainmenu')) }}`. Be aware of the fact that your answer will not work when using a reverse proxy like symfony's or an external one (i.e. varnish).

Comment: @nifr The `request` in `render(controller('::'))` is a `subrequest` and is not same as `request` in a first controller, and also some parameters may be different in them.

Comment: @nifr And I don't said that `controllers as services` is more faster than a `{{ render(controller('controller_service:mainmenu')) }}`, I said that `service` is faster then `{{ render(controller('controller_service:mainmenu')) }}`, because execute less code for it and last but not least service can to solve this tasks more conveniently.