# Symfony 2 - using a form in partial view, controllers function issue with Request

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a partial view, that's displays a form on the DVD's page:

**Partial View with form:**

```
   <div>
         {{ form(form) }}
   </div>
```

**Use of partial view in the DVD's page:**

```
{{ render(controller(
      'DVDBundle:Actors:addActor',
      { 'dvdId': dvd.id }
)) }}
```

The idea is that admin can add actors using the form on the dvd page (url: `website/dvdpage`)

However: the function `addActor` in controller `Actors` doesnt seem to have anything in Request because its used via partial view:

**Controllers function:**

```
 public function addActorAction(Request $request, $dvdId)
 {
   //form related code...
   ......
   ...
 }
```

When checked what's inside: `$request` I get:

```
_fragment?_path=_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Den%26_controller%3DDVDBundle%253AActors%253AaddActor
```

and the error is forbidden access 403. here:

```
 if (!$request->isMethodSafe()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }
```

The strange part is that if i go to that view directly via url : `website/addactor` then that same form works and the Request has correct value in same controller.

I found this:

> When using a controller instead of a URL, you must enable the Symfony
>   fragments configuration:

added exact line to my config: fragments: { path: /_fragment }
but still nothing.

But have no idea how and what to do? Any help?

Comment: You could try just passing the original page request as a parameter in the render call. For reference couple of related SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326839/symfony2-in-twig-pass-request-with-render-function & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427321/symfony2-internal-route-in-twig-render-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, this worked for me, passing in the request as a parameter to the controllers function:

```
{{ render(controller(
      'DVDBundle:Actors:addActor',
      { 'dvdId': dvd.id, 'request': app.request }
)) }}
```

Note, you also need to update the routing to include second parameter like this:

```
add_actor:
  url:   addactor/{dvdId}-{request}
  ....
```