# Issue with pathinfo symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I follow the tips here [Symfony2 internal route in Twig render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427321/symfony2-internal-route-in-twig-render-function) it was very helpfull but when I send on server, the request.pathInfo is null. 
Have you ever had this issue ? here are my codes

```
{% render(controller('projetchMauleonBundle:Mauleon:menu', {'request': app.request})) %}
```

my controller

```
public function menuAction($request)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repositoryEquipe = $em->getRepository('projetchMauleonBundle:Equipe');
    $tabEquipes = $repositoryEquipe->findAll();

    return $this->render('projetchMauleonBundle:Mauleon:menu2.html.twig', array('tabEquipes'=>$tabEquipes, 'request'=>$request));
}
```

And my view :

```
{% if request.pathInfo|slice(1,5) == 'ehpad' or request.pathInfo|slice(1,7) == "equipe"  %}
    <a id="fontDrop" href="{{path('projetch_mauleon_admissionEhpad')}}">Votre admission</a>
{% elseif request.pathInfo|slice(1,3) == 'ssr' %}
    <a id="fontDrop" href="{{path('projetch_mauleon_admissionSsr')}}">Votre admission</a>
{% endif %}
```

Thank you

Comment: I checked it briefly in my symfony project: I think it should not be camel case: use *request.pathinfo* instead of *request.pathInfo*.

Comment: I try it and unfortunatelly it give me an error

Comment: What error? Put the error here.

Comment: Impossible to access an attribute ("pathinfo") on a null variable in projetchMauleonBundle:Mauleon:menu2.html.twig at line 86
Not a very interesting error i think

Comment: I think it's not necessary to pass request when you render controller in first view. You can just use 'app.request' directly in meny2.html.twig. Why don't you do that? then you won't have to pass request into template.

Comment: And one more point: use type hinting in controller action. Replace menuAction($request) with menuAction(Request $request) and add 'use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;' line in use section of the controller.

Comment: I love you.. really  Thank's guy !